# How to add closet rod support?

Tags: closet

I fear the weight level in my closet on the cheap thin metal rod and need to support it in the middle.

I bought a metal support bracket and the support part of the bracket doesn't meet the rod, it's lower than it.

Do I keep shopping for a match or is there an alternative method here?

This is just holding it against the wall as a test fit (not drilled into wall):

[image]

edit:

I've been asked to add a few more pics.

The bracket itself is not adjustable; or I wouldn't be here asking this question. The diagonal rod is spot welded by the manufacturer (STANLEY).

The rod itself is metal and uses one of these round inserts that I screwed into the wall. Oh, and the round thing the rod sits in is not going anywhere; i stripped all the bolts in it upon tightening by drill  =(

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does the end of the shelf look like? Can the rod be moved?

Comment: Yes you can either lower the rod or raise the shelf or look for a different support. 

Comment: Nice picture so far. But following what @isherwood said please take another photo showing how things look at the place where the metal rod and shelf come at the end.

Comment: I have now added pics of the rod. ArchonOSX, you can see why I placed the rod where I did now in the new pics. It's into a wood that is in the drywall, not into the drywall directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most often the ends of the closet rod are captured in some type of round pocket holders that attach to the shelf support board. So the rod could be removed from these and thus be re-positioned.

Your easiest solution may very well be to purchase two more of these same support brackets and install one on each end and one in the middle as you showed in your picture. The rod can then be supported by the three new brackets in similar manner.

I am not a huge fan of metal closet rods and by far prefer a wooden rod. With the three bracket solution you have the option to replace the metal one with a wooden one.

Comment: hmm. Not imagining a wooden closet rod. Can you link me to a rod and brackets as an example?

Comment: Why do I need to link you to different brackets? I already suggested you purchase two more of what you already have and install them at the ends of the shelf. Your existing rod simply sits in the three brackets and no longer uses those round pocket holders. As you have said you cannot lower the pocket holders anyway. As for wooden closet rods....go to the big box store.

Comment: Oh; understood, you want me to abandon the round inserts. Sorry, I read your answer quickly and didn't catch. Thank you Michael, you always seem to be answering my questions on this site :)

Comment: Do note that a wooden closet rod might be a different diameter than a metal rod and it could take selection of a bracket with a different size support hook on the end.

Comment: I should also clarify that to get proper installation of the brackets that you showed you may want to extend a short piece of wood down from the shelf support board (same thickness) that shims out for the lower part of the bracket.

Comment: Actually, sorry, last question for real this time. Can the metal rods go into drywall directly or do they need their own supporting wood before the drywall? Only the middle of the closet has wood coming out; the ends are only drywall.

Comment: I think you answered what I asked at the same time :) -- would you nail or screw the extended wood pieces in? I'm really not a huge fan of screws into drywall unless it's in a strong anchor. I suppose I can try a drywall screw here and see if they hold.

Comment: The bracket installation will be into the corner studs at the back of the shelf. Nothing needed into the side walls. As for removing the round cup bracket you can drill off the screw heads or try cutting away the bracket with a Dremel tool. The possible reason that the screws stripped so much when you installed them was that you neglected to drill pilot holes for the screws. So not make that same mistake when you install the new brackets.